# Is the Hadley cell a problem for the air mass?

Tags: climatology, air-currents

I was lately studying how air masses are generally formed. I came to know that as the warm air rises up and then cools down as it moves above, after some time, a whole cold mass of air is accrued near the equator which leads to the development of air mass. If this is indeed true, then does Hadley cell cause destruction of a potential air mass? Because, it leads to the circulation of the air from the equatorial to the sub-tropical region, which ultimately means that it breaks down the accumulated mass of the cold air and hence prevents the formation of an air mass.

Kindly enlighten me with the truth!

Comment: can you show what you have been reading ?

Comment: The Hadley cell is itself an air mass.